# Sort Order formula to alphabetise in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing, excel-formula, vba

I am currently drawing up a spreadsheet that will automatically remove duplicates and alphabetize a list:

[image]

I am using the COUNTIF() function in column G to create a sort order and then VLOOKUP() to find the sort in column J.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to get my **SortOrder** column to function properly. At the moment it creates an index for two number 1's meaning the cell highlighted in yellow is missed out and the last entry in the sorted list is null:

[image]

If anyone can find and rectify this mistake for me I'll be very grateful as it has been driving me insane all day! Many thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to sort column J?  What's the formula you're using in J?

Comment: What is the nature of *20212* in column D? Is it just a number with a forced left alignment or actually text that looks like a number? Can you change your count formula in column G to `=COUNTIF(D$2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",D:D)),"<="&TEXT(D2, "0;@"))` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide my usual method for doing an automatic pulling-in of raw data into a sorted, duplicate-removed list:

Assume raw data is in column A. In column B, use this formula to increase the counter each time the row shows a non-duplicate item in column A. Hardcord B2 to be "1", and use this formula in B3 and drag down.

```
=if(iserror(match(A3,$A$2:A2,0)),B2+1,B2)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that when we refer to this row counter in our revised list, we will use the match function, which only checks for the first matching number. Then say you want your new list of data on column D (usually I do this for display purposes, so either 'group-out' [hide] columns that form the formulas, or do this on another tab). You can avoid this step, but if you are already using helper columns I usually do each step in a different column - easier to document. In column C, starting in C3 [C2 hardcoded to 1] and drag down, just have a simple counter, which error-checks to the stop at the end of your list:

```
=if(C2<max(B:B),C2+1," ")
```

Then in column D, starting at D2 and dragged down:

```
=iferror(index(A:A,match(C2,B:B,0)),"")
```

The index function is like half of the vlookup function - it pulls the result out of a given array, when you provide it with a row number. The match function is like the other half of the vlookup function - it provides you with the row number where an item appears in a given array.

Hope this helps you in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason that this is going wrong as implied by Jeeped's comment is that you can't meaningfully compare a string to a number unless you do a conversion because they are stored differently. So COUNTIF counts numbers and text separately.

20212 will give a count of 1 because it is the only (or lowest) number.

CS10Z002 will give a count of 1 because it is the first text string in alphabetical order.

Another approach is to add the count of numbers to the count if the current cell contains text:-

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$D$2:$D$"&$F$3),"<="&D2)+ISTEXT(D2)*COUNT(INDIRECT("$D$2:$D$"&$F$3))
```

It's easier to show the result of three different conversions with some test data:-

(0) No conversion - just use COUNTIF

```
=COUNTIF(D$2:D$7,"<="&D2)
```

"999"<"abc"<"def", 999<1000

(1) Count everything as text

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D$2:D$7&""<=D2&""))
```

"1000"<"999"

(2) Count numbers before text

```
=COUNTIF(D$2:D$7,"<="&D2)+ISTEXT(D2)*COUNT(D$2:D$7)
```

999<1000<"999"

(3) Count everything as text but convert numbers with leading zeroes

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(D$2:D$7,"000000")<=TEXT(D2,"000000")))
```

"000999" = "000999", "000999"<"001000"

[image]